# AWS IoT Core sql query rule - Comparing 2 object arrays returns null/undefined?

Tags: mysql, arrays, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to compare 2 arrays in a sql query. Everything seems to work fine while getting data from dynamodb and MQTT broker server.
But if I try to compare both arrays, doesn't return anything or its undefined.

My sql query:

```
SELECT ts, objects, (SELECT id FROM get_dynamodb('table', 'key_name', 'key_value', 'rolearn').ids) AS db, (SELECT id from objects) as obj_ids
FROM 'subscribed/topic'
WHERE objects <> []
```

Result:

```
{
   "ts": 1615807935588,
   "objects": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "planet": "jupiter"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "planet": "mars"
      },
   ],
   "db": [
      {
         "id": 2
      },
      {
         "id": 3
      }
   ],
   "obj_ids": [
      {
         "id": 1
      },
      {
         "id": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

So far it's ok, now all I want to do is compare if "obj_ids" and "db" arrays are different (obj_ids <> db), and by the aws documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-operators.html#iot-sql-operators-not-eq I can compare both arrays.

So if I do:

```
SELECT ts, objects, (SELECT id FROM get_dynamodb('table', 'key_name', 'key_value', 'rolearn').ids) AS db, (SELECT id from objects) as obj_ids
FROM 'subscribed/topic'
WHERE objects <> []
AND obj_ids <> db
```

The code doesn't return anything. I've already tested comparing 2 objects arrays hardcoded into the query and it works just has I intended.

```
SELECT ([{"id": 1},{"id": 2}] <> [{"id": 1}]) as result
FROM 'subscribed/topic'
```

Result:

```
{
   "result": true
}
```

Any response will be appretiated.
Thanks!

Comment: `obj_ids` and `db` aren't accessible in the `WHERE` clause. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-where.html: "you cannot reference any aliases created with the AS keyword in the SELECT. The WHERE clause is evaluated first, to determine if SELECT is evaluated."

Comment: @BenT yep, you are right! replaced the `obj_ids` and `db` with the `SELECT` and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credits from [Ben T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1373856/ben-t)

As [AWS Docs WHERE clause](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-where.html) says:

> "you cannot reference any aliases created with the AS keyword in the SELECT. The WHERE clause is evaluated first, to determine if SELECT is evaluated."

So all I needed to do is move the `(SELECT id FROM get_dynamodb('table', 'key_name', 'key_value', 'rolearn').ids)` and `(SELECT id from objects)` to the `WHERE` clause.

Final query:

```
SELECT ts, objects
FROM 'subscribed/topic'
WHERE objects <> []
AND (SELECT id from objects) <> (SELECT id FROM get_dynamodb('table', 'key_name', 'key_value', 'rolearn').ids)
```